# ¿Cómo guardar listas bidimensionales en un archivo y posteriormente poder recuperarlas?

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de lista como la siguiente:

```
lista=[["valencia",1,50],["madrid",3,90],["sevilla",2,4]]
```

Necesito almacenar dicha lista en un archivo para poder posteriormente recuperarla cuando sea necesario.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
def guardarDatos():
    lista=[["valencia",1,50],["madrid",3,90],["sevilla",2,4]]
    a=open('texto.txt','w')
    for l in lista:
        a.write(l + ',')
    a.close()
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Hola David, ¿Cómo quieres que quede la lista almacenada en el txt? ¿Cada sublista una fila a modo de csv? Muestra para ese ejemplo como debería verse el txt . Si quieres luego recuperar la lista ¿te has planteado serializarla con pickle en vez de guardarla en un fichero de text?

Comment: Luego tengo que recuperar los datos, es un proyecto y soy nuevo en python la cosa es que tengo un programa en el tengo unos datos que introduzco a mano que seria esos que he puesto de ejemplo, estos datos se guardan en una raiz bidimensional, ya que puedo meter todos los datos que yo quiera, el proyecto me pide que luego de introducir los datos tenga una opción de guardar todo en un archivo y luego poder pre cargar datos.

Answer (score 1):

El error se produce porque estás intentando concatenar una lista (`l`, listas anidadas resultado de iterar sobre `lista`) con una cadena (`','`) en la llamada al método `write`. De todas formas, `write` solo acepta objetos `str` o `bytes` dependiendo del modo en que se abra el archivo, no una lista.

Tienes muchas posibilidades para almacenar la lista y posteriormente recuperarla, dos de las más simples son:

### Usar un archivo csv, que es lo que parece que intentas en tu código:

- Creando el archivo y parseandolo "manualmente":

  ```
  def guardar_datos(datos):
      with open("datos.csv", "w") as f:
          for fila in lista:
              f.write(",".join(str(d) for d in fila) + "\n")

  def cargar_datos():
      with open("datos.csv", "r") as f:
          datos = [[d1, int(d2), int(d3)]
                       for d1, d2, d3 in (l.rstrip().split(",") for l in f)]
          return datos

  lista = [["valencia", 1, 50], ["madrid", 3, 90], ["sevilla", 2, 4]]
  guardar_datos(lista)
  datos = cargar_datos()
  ```

  Dado que tus listas tienen primer elemento que es una cadena y dos que son enteros es necesario un casting a `str` primero antes de usar `write` y después un casting a `int` cuando recuperamos los datos.
  ",".join usa la propietaria del método  para unir los elementos de un iterable que contenga cadenas en una sola cadena:

  ```
  >>> lista = ["madrid", "3", "90"]
  >>> ",".join(lista)
  'madrid,3,90'
  ```
- Usando el módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) de la biblioteca estándar:

  ```
  import csv


  def guardar_datos(datos):
      with open("datos.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
          writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
          writer.writerows(datos)


  def cargar_datos():
       with open("datos.csv", "r", newline='') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
          datos = [[d1, int(d2), int(d3)] for d1, d2, d3 in reader]
          return datos



  lista = [["valencia", 1, 50], ["madrid", 3, 90], ["sevilla", 2, 4]]
  guardar_datos(lista)
  datos = cargar_datos()
  ```

  > **Nota:** en Python 2 eliminar el parámetro `newline` de `open` y abrir el archivo en modo binario ("rb" y "wb").

Ambas formas te genera un csv como el siguiente:

> valencia,1,50
>   madrid,3,90
>   sevilla,2,4

### Serializando el objeto con [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)/cPickle:

```
import pickle


def guardar_datos(datos):
    with open("datos.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(datos, f)


def cargar_datos():
     with open("datos.pkl", "rb") as f:
         return pickle.load(f)

lista = [["valencia", 1, 50], ["madrid", 3, 90], ["sevilla", 2, 4]]
guardar_datos(lista)
datos = cargar_datos()
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción más, guardarlo como [JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), ya que en tu caso los elementos contenidos en cada lista son simples cadenas y números.

### Guardar los datos:

```
import json
lista=[["valencia",1,50],["madrid",3,90],["sevilla",2,4]]
with open("lista.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(lista, f)
```

### Leerlos de nuevo

```
import json
with open("lista.json", "r") as f:
  leido = json.load(f)
```

El fichero `lista.json` que se ha generado es de texto, puedes verlo con cualquier editor e incluso modificarlo. La sintaxis de JSON es casi idéntica a la de una lista python. Éste sería el contenido del fichero:

```
$ cat lista.json
[["valencia", 1, 50], ["madrid", 3, 90], ["sevilla", 2, 4]]
```